# Make @Html.RadioButtonFor Required

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have div where user should select gender and submit the form. How to make this radio button required without default value?

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <p>Select Gender:</p>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.One, "Male") Male<br>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.One, "Female") Female<br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you should add some javascript validations like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "reg", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1", name = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                Gender: "required"},
messages: {
                Gender: "Please check a value" },
 submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```